# Rotating Camera around a player object on both X and Y axis with mouse button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to rotate the camera angle on my third person player game object on both X and Y axes by using the middle mouse button.

I have this code below.

```
public class CameraControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public Vector3 offset;

    public float pitch = 2f;
    private float turnSpeed = 5f;
    private float currentZoom = 10f;

    void LateUpdate()
    {

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(2))
        {
            offset = Quaternion.AngleAxis(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * turnSpeed, Vector3.up) * offset;
            offset = Quaternion.AngleAxis(Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * turnSpeed, Vector3.right) * offset;
        }

        transform.position = player.position - offset * currentZoom;
        transform.LookAt(player.position + Vector3.up * pitch);

    }

}
```

Rotating in single axes seem to work as expected, I can rotate along X axis or Y axis without any problems, however when they mix up (moving in both directions at the same time) then some things seem to break and the rotation seems to not work as well. It's as if it loses its ability to move along the Y axis along the way.

Another problem is that I'm not quite sure how to limit the Y axis so that the rotation doesn't go below ground or above and around the player's head. I thought about using Mathf.Clamp but setting the min and the max values seems too problematic in my code as it currently is.

Answer (score 1):

For the [`Quaternion` operator `*`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-operator_multiply.html) the order matters! It is `currentRotation * additionalRotation`.

Also usually what you want to do in order to not get a tilted rotation

- rotate around the **global** Y axis
- rotate around the **local** X axis

I think it should rather be something like

```
if (Input.GetMouseButton(2))
{
    offset *= Quaternion.AngleAxis(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * turnSpeed, Vector3.up);
    offset *= Quaternion.AngleAxis(Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * turnSpeed, transform.right);
}
```

---

In general I would propose a different approach

I would give the camera a parent object and place that parent object at the position where to look at (your player).

Then youove the camera on the negative local Z axis (zoom).

For the rotation you rather simply rotate the parent object.

Hierarchy

```
 - CameraAnchor
 |--Camera (With CameraControl)
```

and then do something like

```
public class CameraControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public Vector3 offset;

    public float pitch = 2f;
    private float turnSpeed = 5f;
    private float currentZoom = 10f;

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        // Center the parent on the player with an optional offset
        transform.parent.position = player.position + offset;

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(2))
        {
            // Simply rotate the parent accordingly
            // Since the camera is a child of it it will automatically be moved in an orbit
            transform.parent.rotation *= Quaternion.AngleAxis(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * turnSpeed, Vector3.up);
            transform.parent.rotation *= Quaternion.AngleAxis(Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * turnSpeed, transform.parent.right);
        }

        // For the zoom simply move the camera in its local space forward and backward
        // A higher value for currentZoom means further away 
        // so you might want to either change the name or use something like 1/currentZoom
        transform.localPosition = Vector3.back * currentZoom;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem I have with the code you provided is that the rotation tilts the camera entirely rather than staying on the X-axis. Is there a possible solution to this?